# VBA Copy Specific Cells To Specific Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to copy data from one sheet to another upon specfic cell values being found.

```
Sub Extract()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long
    Dim strProject As String
    Dim RDate As Date
    Dim RVal As Single
    Dim BlnProjExists As Boolean
    With Sheets("Enhancements").Range("B3")
    For i = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To 13
            .Offset(i, j) = ""
        Next j
    Next i
End With
With Sheets("AllData").Range("E3")
    For i = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
    strProject = .Offset(i, 0)
    RDate = .Offset(i, 3)
    RVal = .Offset(i, 4)
     If InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "Enhancements") > 0 Then
            strProject = .Offset(i, 0)
        ElseIf InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "OVH") > 0 And RVal > 0 Then
            strProject = .Offset(i, -1)
        Else
            GoTo NextLoop
        End If

        With Sheets("Enhancements").Range("B3")
            If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                .Offset(1, 0) = strProject
                j = 1
            Else
                BlnProjExists = False
                For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
                    If .Offset(j, 0) = strProject Then
                        BlnProjExists = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                If BlnProjExists = False Then
 .Offset(j, 0) = strProject
                End If
            End If
            Select Case Format(RDate, "mmm yy")
                Case "Apr 13"
                    m = 1
                Case "May 13"
                    m = 2
                Case "Jun 13"
                    m = 3
                Case "Jul 13"
                    m = 4
                Case "Aug 13"
                    m = 5
                Case "Sep 13"
                    m = 6
                Case "Oct 13"
                    m = 7
                Case "Nov 13"
                    m = 8
                Case "Dec 13"
                    m = 9
                Case "Jan 14"
                    m = 10
                Case "Feb 14"
                    m = 11
                Case "Mar 14"
                    m = 12
            End Select
            .Offset(j, m) = .Offset(j, m) + RVal
        End With
NextLoop:
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

The code works, but I've been trying to adapt a section of this script which I'm having a real difficulty in doing.

The piece of the script which I need to change is as below:

```
If InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "Enhancements") > 0 Then
                strProject = .Offset(i, 0)
            ElseIf InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "OVH") > 0 And RVal > 0 Then
                strProject = .Offset(i, -1)
            Else
                GoTo NextLoop
            End If

            With Sheets("Enhancements").Range("B3")
                If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    .Offset(1, 0) = strProject
                    j = 1
                Else
```

In it's current format, if the text values of "Enhancements" or "OVH" are found the data is copied and pasted to the "Enhancements" sheet.

I'd like to change this, so if the text value "Enhancements" is found the information is pasted to the "Enhancements" page and if the text value of "OVH" is found, the information is pasted into the "Overheads" sheet. The rest of the code can remain as it is.

As I say I've tried to make the changes but I seem to fall foul to errors surrounding the use of the 'If', ElseIf' and 'Else' statements.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The bounty proposes that "The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns."  I believe this is not true.  All I see here is some VBA that needs refactoring and debugging.

Comment: Hi @Smandoli, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and my sincere apologies for causing offence. I'm not sure whether there is anything I can do to change the bounty, but could you possibly tell me please, are you able to help? Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data is a little confusing, I have presumed that on the overheads sheet you want the overheads code to be from the task column.  For the enhancements you want the code to be the project name.

If that's is incorrect, please provide better sample data.

Try this code:

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim rLookup As Range, rFound As Range
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim lMonthIndex As Long, lProjectIndex As Long
    Dim vData As Variant, vMonths As Variant
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim vbDict As Object

    With Worksheets("AllData")
        Set rLookup = .Range("E3", .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        Set rFound = .Range("E3")
    End With

    Set vbDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vMonths = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3)

    For iLoop = 0 To 1
        lRow = 0: lLastRow = 3
        vbDict.RemoveAll: ReDim vData(rLookup.Count, 13)
        Do
            Set rFound = Worksheets("AllData").Cells.Find(Array("Enhancements", "OVH")(iLoop), _
                rFound, , , xlByRows, xlNext, False)
            If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If rFound.Row <= lLastRow Then Exit Do
            lMonthIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Month(CDate(rFound.Offset(, 4).Value)), vMonths, False)
            If vbDict.exists(rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value) Then
                lProjectIndex = vbDict.Item(rFound.Value)
                vData(lProjectIndex, lMonthIndex) = _
                vData(lProjectIndex, lMonthIndex) + rFound.Offset(, 4).Value
            Else
                vbDict.Add rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value, lRow
                vData(lRow, 0) = rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value
                vData(lRow, lMonthIndex) = rFound.Offset(, 4).Value
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
            lLastRow = rFound.Row
        Loop
        If iLoop = 0 Then
            With Worksheets("Enhancements")
                .Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
                .Range("B4").Resize(vbDict.Count + 1, 13).Value = vData
            End With
        Else
            With Worksheets("Overheads")
                .Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
                .Range("B4").Resize(vbDict.Count + 1, 13).Value = vData
            End With
        End If
    Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Commented version:

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim rLookup As Range, rFound As Range
    Dim lLastRow As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim lMonthIndex As Long, lProjectIndex As Long
    Dim vData As Variant, vMonths As Variant
    Dim iLoop As Integer
    Dim vbDict As Object

    '// Get the projects range to loop through
    With Worksheets("AllData")
        Set rLookup = .Range("E3", .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        Set rFound = .Range("E3")
    End With

    '// Use a latebinded dictionary to store the project names.
    Set vbDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    '// Create an array of the months to get the correct columns.  Instead of your select case method
    vMonths = Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3)

    '// Loop through both search requirements
    For iLoop = 0 To 1
        '// Set the counters - lLastRow is used to make sure the loop is not never ending.
        lRow = 0: lLastRow = 3
        '// Clear the dictionary and create the projects array.
        vbDict.RemoveAll: ReDim vData(rLookup.Count, 13)
        Do
            '// Search using the criteria requried
            Set rFound = Worksheets("AllData").Cells.Find(Array("Enhancements", "OVH")(iLoop), _
                rFound, , , xlByRows, xlNext, False)
            '//  Make sure something was found and its not a repeat.
            If rFound Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If rFound.Row <= lLastRow Then Exit Do
            '//  Get the correct month column using our months array and the project date.
            lMonthIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Month(CDate(rFound.Offset(, 4).Value)), vMonths, False)
            '// Check if the project exists.
            If vbDict.exists(rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value) Then
                '// Yes it exists so add the actuals to the correct project/month.
                lProjectIndex = vbDict.Item(rFound.Value)
                vData(lProjectIndex, lMonthIndex) = _
                vData(lProjectIndex, lMonthIndex) + rFound.Offset(, 4).Value
            Else
                '// No it doesnt exist, create it and then add the actuals to the correct project/month
                vbDict.Add rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value, lRow
                vData(lRow, 0) = rFound.Offset(, -iLoop).Value
                vData(lRow, lMonthIndex) = rFound.Offset(, 4).Value
                '// Increase the project count.
                lRow = lRow + 1
            End If
            '// Set the last row = the last found row to ensure we dont repeat the search.
            lLastRow = rFound.Row
        Loop
        If iLoop = 0 Then
            '// Clear the enhancements sheet and populate the cells from the array
            With Worksheets("Enhancements")
                .Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
                .Range("B4").Resize(vbDict.Count + 1, 13).Value = vData
            End With
        Else
            '// Clear the overheads sheet and populate the cells from the array
            With Worksheets("Overheads")
                .Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
                .Range("B4").Resize(vbDict.Count + 1, 13).Value = vData
            End With
        End If
    Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Readify, thank you very much for taking the time to put this together. I've incoporated your code into my spreadsheet, but undfortunately when I run this, I receive the following error Run- time error '13' type mismatch and it highlights this line as the cause of the error: lMonthIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Month(CDate(rFound(1, 4).Value)), vMonths, False). I hope this helps, many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Readify, that's got it, the script now runs perfectly. Thank you so very much for putting this together, especially the commented version which I'll be able to learn from. All the best and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Readify, I'm very sorry to trouble you with this, but I just wondered whether you may have made another change to the code above because when I try to run the code this morning, I'm back to receiving the Run- time error '13' type mismatch error. Again highlighting this line as the cause of the error: lMonthIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Month(CDate(rFound(1, 4).Value)), vMonths, False). I'm using a machine with Excel 2003 at work rather than my home which is Excel 2013 if that helps. Could you possibly look at this for me please. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Try using `rFound.Offset(, 3).Value`, if that doesnt work its likely that the value in the cell is not a date. Step through the code to check this. If you have cells that don't have a date then you will need to add a check first to make sure the value is a date.  ie `If IsDate(rFound(, 3).value) Then`

Comment: Hi @Reafidy, thank you very much for coming back to me with this, and I'm very sorry to cause you trouble, but I've been through the source data and manually changed all the dates to 01/05/13 using the format dd/mm/yy, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same problem. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM No problem.  Because the code executes without any error using the sample you provided, can you post another sample workbook which does throws the error.  Then I can troubleshoot it.

Comment: unfortunately I can't because it contains sensitive information. Rather than you spending all day on this. I'll have a look at the file that I'm using at home and see if I can see any difference between the two files. I'll then get back to you if that's ok? Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: I'm very sorry to trouble you again, but I've been able to perform some more testing on this and I've found where the problem lies. If there is data in column G of the 'Source' sheet the macro won't, producing the error as b efore. If however, I delete all the information, the code works perfectly, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Column G on the 'Source' file is a text field with values for example as 'C&R Analyst'. I hope this helps, and many thanks for all your time, trouble and patience. Kind Regards

Comment: I have added data to column g and the code executes without an issue  on your sample worksheet.  No where does the code look at column G so I don't think that's the issue unless...    either the pattern of sample data has changed, or the code has changed.  You can either strip out the sensitive data and post a workbook which contains the bug.  Or you can sign up at ww.ozgrid.com/forum where I am an admin under the same name and private message me the workbook with the bug.

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to let you know I've sent you a private message using Ozgrid. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Whoops, my mistake I dropped the ball there. It should be `rFound.Offset(, 4).Value`.  It was looking in the wrong column.  Also please change the row found line too `If rFound.Row <= lLastRow Then Exit Do` note I have added the = sign.  This is to prevent an endless loop.  I have update the code above.

Comment: Hi @Reafidy, thank you very much for this. I've sent you a message via Ozgrid. Many thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up rewriting a lot of your code to make it more efficient, this should accomplish what you're looking for, and it should run rather quickly also:

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim cllProjects As Collection
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsEnha As Worksheet
    Dim wsOver As Worksheet
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngProject As Range
    Dim arrProjects() As Variant
    Dim varProjectType As Variant
    Dim ProjectIndex As Long
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim dRVal As Double
    Dim dRDate As Double
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strProjectFirst As String
    Dim strProject As String

    Set wsData = Sheets("AllData")
    Set wsEnha = Sheets("Enhancements")
    Set wsOver = Sheets("Overheads")

    wsEnha.Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    wsOver.Range("B4:O" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    With wsData.Range("E4", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 4 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each varProjectType In Array("Enhancements", "OVH")
            Set cllProjects = New Collection
            ProjectIndex = 0
            ReDim arrProjects(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & varProjectType & "*"), 1 To 14)
            Set rngFound = .Find(varProjectType, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart)
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirst = rngFound.Address
                Do
                    strProject = vbNullString
                    dRDate = wsData.Cells(rngFound.Row, "H").Value2
                    dRVal = wsData.Cells(rngFound.Row, "I").Value2

                    If varProjectType = "OVH" And dRVal > 0 Then
                        strProject = wsData.Cells(rngFound.Row, "D").Text
                        Set rngFind = Intersect(.EntireRow, wsData.Columns("D"))
                    ElseIf varProjectType = "Enhancements" Then
                        strProject = wsData.Cells(rngFound.Row, "E").Text
                        Set rngFind = .Cells
                    End If

                    If Len(strProject) > 0 Then
                        cllProjects.Add LCase(strProject), LCase(strProject)
                        If cllProjects.Count > ProjectIndex Then
                            ProjectIndex = cllProjects.Count
                            arrProjects(ProjectIndex, 1) = strProject
                            Set rngProject = Intersect(rngFound.EntireRow, Columns(rngFind.Column))
                            strProjectFirst = rngProject.Address
                            Do
                                If LCase(rngProject.Text) = LCase(strProject) Then
                                    dRDate = wsData.Cells(rngProject.Row, "H").Value2
                                    dRVal = wsData.Cells(rngProject.Row, "I").Value2
                                    cIndex = Month(dRDate) - 2 + (Year(dRDate) - 2013) * 12
                                    arrProjects(ProjectIndex, cIndex) = arrProjects(ProjectIndex, cIndex) + dRVal
                                End If
                                Set rngProject = rngFind.Find(arrProjects(ProjectIndex, 1), rngProject, xlValues, xlPart)
                            Loop While rngProject.Address <> strProjectFirst
                        End If
                    End If
                    Set rngFound = .Find(varProjectType, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
                Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
            End If

            If cllProjects.Count > 0 Then
                Select Case varProjectType
                    Case "Enhancements":    wsEnha.Range("B4").Resize(cllProjects.Count, UBound(arrProjects, 2)).Value = arrProjects
                    Case "OVH":             wsOver.Range("B4").Resize(cllProjects.Count, UBound(arrProjects, 2)).Value = arrProjects
                End Select
                Set cllProjects = Nothing
            End If

        Next varProjectType
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Set cllProjects = Nothing
    Set wsData = Nothing
    Set wsEnha = Nothing
    Set wsOver = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing
    Set rngProject = Nothing
    Erase arrProjects

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @tigeravatar, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for all the time you've spent on putting the revised code together, it's greatly appreciated. I've tried the code and on the whole it works great. However when it comes to the 'OVH' extraction the correct description and the sum function of the man hours doesn't work. I appreciate that it may be a little difficult to work out where it's going wrong by just my explanation. Would it be easier if I posted a demo file?  Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM please post a demo file or edit your question to be more clear

Comment: @IRHM When I test the code it seems to perform as desired.  An example file showing expected results would go a long way to helping understand what it is you are looking for, but at the same time you should be able to adjust the code to suit your specific needs.  If you are having trouble adjusting the code, please post what is giving you issues and why. (And again, a sample file would be very helpful)

Comment: Hi @tigeravatar, thank you for coming back to me with this. Please find the link to my file below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/28qre2czn0un1c3/Dropbox%20Test.xls

On the "Macros" sheet you'll see there are two buttons, one linked to my original code, and the other to the script you kindly provided.

The data shown on the "Enhancements" sheet has been extracted using my code. You'll see a number of rows highlighted, these rows should appear on the 'Overheads' page when I run your code. When I do use your code these sum totals are missing. I hope this helps. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @tigeravatar, thank you very much for taking the time to come back to me with this and for correcting the code which works fine. All the very best and kind regards.